# Remove Bloatware on my Xperia L

Tags: bloatware

I'm try to remove bloatware on my old xperia, but then this is happening

```
shell@android:/ $ pm uninstall -k --users 0 com.google.android.apps.books
Error: Unknown option: --users
```

and then I try this, but same result

```
shell@android:/ $ pm uninstall -k 0 com.google.android.apps.books
```

Failure

Comment: You will need to root your phone to remove bloatware

Answer (score 1):

It should be --user 0 not --users 0

Also - k flag is optional

But to acknowledge a comment you must be rooted to completely remove bloatware, because if you add another account or work profile that user will have that stuff. You, however, don't